# Selecting and updating multiple rows using Ruby ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have an array of user uuids and I want to update one field that all of those users have(I am guaranteed that they have a value for that field).

I know that I should be using `update_all` to update all of the fields in one transaction. However, I'm not sure how to select users given an array of user uuids that can then be supplied to the `update_all`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.where(uuid: [uuid_array])` will return an ActiveRecord Relation, on which you can call `update_all`.